# Working with texts: change all letters to lowercase in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with a .txt dataset which I read in as a csv file.

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.txt', delimiter='\t', header=None, names=['category', 'text'], dtype=str)
print data.head()
```

it prints:

```
0  MUSIC  Today at the recording studio, John...
1  POLITICS  The tensions inside the government have...
2  NEWS  The new pictures of NASA show...
```

What I want to do, is change all the letters from the text to lowercase. So, for example, "The new pictures of NASA show..." would become "the new pictures of nasa show...", but "NEWS" remains uppercase as "NEWS".

Any words of advice?

Answer (score 4):

You can apply a lambda which will do this for you:

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.txt', delimiter='\t', header=None, names=['category', 'text'], dtype=str).apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

Using your example data, you'll see this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv('train.txt', delimiter='\t', header=None, names=['category', 'text'], dtype=str).apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
>>> data.head()
   category                                        text
0     music      today at the recording studio, john...
1  politics  the tensions inside the government have...
2      news            the new pictures of nasa show...
```

Comment: This is awesome, but it also lowers "TEXT, MUSIC, NEWS". Another thing: the actually text I work with is in Cyrillic, so now I see that everything I've tried has failed solely because of that. Thanks for you help! :)

Comment: @saremisona Your filename makes me think you're training a machine learning model. Your classes for training being lowercase shouldn't change anything. I thought lowercase handled unicode, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I'm training a classifier for texts in categories. Don't you think it makes a difference with count vectorizer and tf idf if some words contain uppercase letters or not?

Comment: @saremisona tf-idf cares very much whether words are capitalized or not. They're different words as far as the algorithm can tell. This is why normalization (lower-casing in this case) is so important.